# Is it wrong to enquire about the progress of a background check

Tags: hiring-process, hiring

I've been offered a job contingent on a background check. Today is the7th business day since the offer. 
Should I be worried about the amount of time? 
Would it be wrong of me to contact the gentleman who offered me the job to enquire about the progress of the background check?

Comment: Did the company give you a time frame?

Comment: Have you lived in lots of different places in the last 7 years (the usual time a background check covers, IIRC)? My last background check took 3 weeks  because I had 5+ residence addresses over the previous 7 years, almost all of them in different states. Some states/municipalities are slower than molasses in wintertime when it comes to digging up records. A week would not be at all unusual in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can inquire and see how far they are. Sometimes they take a while if your references can not be reached easily. Also, people get sick, etc. There are plenty of reasons it could take a while. Mine took about two weeks and it was because the people I listed as a reference weren't answering their phones.

Comment: I just asked/posted this question. Should/could I ask a former employer to call or reach out to new manager to give a personal reference?

Comment: I know there's a third party doing the background check. But do they only contact the HR dept? Or do they contact your direct supervisor/manager? Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Background checks can take a long time. A "contingency" like that makes the "offer" very open ended. I would consider the offer not an offer, but more an "expression of interest" until it becomes real. The employer should have told you how long it would take and you are certainly justified in calling him to find out what the timeline is.

Until the offer becomes real, you should not "accept" it or stop looking for other positions. At our company we complete background checks BEFORE making a written offer.